# How to transform multiple messages into single message?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

every day we will get below messages in Student-Topic-In

```
Message 1: {"StudentID": "1", "StudentName":"aaa","fatherName":"aaa1",  "class":"1"}
Message 2: {"StudentID": "2", "StudentName":"bbb","fatherName":"bbb1",  "class":"1"}
Message 3: {"StudentID": "3", "StudentName":"ccc","fatherName":"ccc1",  "class":"2"}
Message 4: {"StudentID": "4", "StudentName":"ddd","fatherName":"ddd1",  "class":"2"}
Message 5: {"StudentID": "5", "StudentName":"eee","fatherName":"eee1",  "class":"2"}
```

And the end of the day(once in a day) based on each class, we have to consolidate all the messages and publish to "Student-Topic-Out" in below format.

```
Message 1:{"Class":"1"
          {"StudentID": "1", "StudentName":"aaa","fatherName":"aaa1"},
          {"StudentID": "2", "StudentName":"bbb","fatherName":"bbb1"}
       }
Message 2:{"Class":"2" 
          {"StudentID": "3", "StudentName":"ccc","fatherName":"ccc1"},
          {"StudentID": "4", "StudentName":"ddd","fatherName":"ddd1"},
          {"StudentID": "5", "StudentName":"eee","fatherName":"eee1"}
       }
```

I tried the following, but don't know how to create a student list without class name?

```
KStream<String, Object> sampleStream = builder.stream("Student-Topic-in");
    sampleStream
            .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
            .mapValues(v -> (Student) v)
            .groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getClass_name(), v))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5000))
            //I am not sure how to create a student list without Classname
            .aggregate(Student::new, (k, v, list) -> (Student)list.add((Student)v)
```

Could you please let me know, how to construct output JSON message Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `KStream.groupBy(...).windowedBy().aggregate().mapValues` using the "class" attribute for grouping.

In the `Aggregator()` you can assemble a `List` of students that you transform into `JSON` in `mapValues()`

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the messages in a list in following way :

```
KStream<String, Object> sampleStream = builder.stream("Student-Topic-in");
   KTable<Windowed<key>,List<Student>> aggregatedTable =  sampleStream
            .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
            .mapValues(v -> (Student) v)
            .groupBy((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair(v.getClass_name(), v))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(5000))
            //I am not sure how to create a student list without Classname
            .aggregate(ArrayList::new, (k, v, list) -> list.add((Student)v, 
               Materialized.with(keySerde(), arrayListSerde())
 )
```

Once you get the `List<Student>`, it can be converted to any desired format using `.mapValues()` function.